# Attiny 1634 not found in tools menu Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino, attiny

I have developed a design using arduino uno r3 and I would like to use attiny 1634 instead of atmega 328p. Learnt how to program attiny 85 using arduino isp. Need help for programming the attiny 1634,  couldnot find the attiny 1634 board in the tools menu of the arduino IDE. Did some research online and found out that i need to write a header file for attiny 1634. Please help with this header file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the chip is not supported in the standard Arduino IDE by default. But there is a GitHub project, called [arduino-tiny](https://github.com/rambo/arduino-tiny/tree/attiny1634), that integrates ATtiny 1634 support in the IDE.